# Is it possible to move a parent object independent of the child object

Tags: unity

I need to be able to move a Parent Object without moving the Child Objects.

Comment: No. If you do not want a child to move with its parent, then do not make it a child of that parent. Parenting means "I want this child object to move with its parent". If what you want is something different, try editing your question to describe what it is you want, and we can help you find other ways to achieve it.

Comment: I have a different solution already. It's just that it would be more efficient to do it this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you do not want a child to move with its parent, then do not make it a child of that parent. Parenting means "I want this child object to move with its parent".

If that's not the behaviour you want, then this is not the hammer for your particular nail, and you should look for a different relationship that isn't transformation parenting.